# Put your name up on something

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> ***Put your names up on*** the board.
>
> (He is ordering them to write their name on the board.)

Can I use these versions instead of the first sentence?

> 2- ***Put your names on*** the board.
>
> 3- ***Put your names down on*** the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes to all 3**. However although the third answer is technically correct (down is used as an adverb related to writing). I personally would not use it in this situation as it sounds awkward. Boards are usually up not down and the use of "up on (atop) the board" is related to the top of the board, so to now used down does not sound correct.

[Link clarifying relationship between Atop and up on](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/atop?s=t)

Comment: I agree, the only situation **down** seems appropriate is if the board is not hanging on a wall, but rather horizontal (eg. on a desk or table)